# Problema con declaración de funciones en python

Tags: python

me encuentro aprendiendo python y estoy en la sección de funciones, realizando un ejercicio el cual consiste en solicitar un nombre, imprimirlo, modifícarlo e imprimirlo de nuevo pude observar que no se modifica correctamente el nombre, no se si estoy declarando mal las funciones o por que no  funciona mi código, si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería mucho, código a continuación.

```py
def imprimirNombre():
    print("Nombre : " + nombre)
    return nombre

def modificarNombre():
    nombre = input("\n Digita tu nombre : ")
    print()
    return nombre


nombre = input("\n Digita tu nombre : ")
print()

opcion = 4;

while opcion != 0:
    opcion = int(input("\n Digita una opcion : "))

    if opcion == 1:
        # Imprimir Nombre
        imprimirNombre()

    elif opcion == 2:
        #Modificar Nombre
        modificarNombre()

    elif opcion == 3:
        # Terminar Ejecucion
        opcion = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que python maneja scopes, si tu variable esta dentro de una función se creara una variable local , en tu codigo estas creando una variable en un ámbito local en la función `modificarNombre()` que es la que le asignas el  `input()` cuando le dices que retorne el valor de dicha variable , estas devolviendo la variable local de la función mencionada anteriormente y  no estas modificando realmente tu variable `name` que tienes en el ambito global , por esta razón una solución seria que devuelvas el valor de la variable local de la función `modificarNombre()` y que este resultado devuelto sea asignado a tu variable `name` global , de esta forma , si se modifica el nombre realmente , te dejo el codigo modificado para que lo revises , cualquier duda dejala en los comentarios , suerte :)

```
def imprimirNombre():
    print("Nombre : " + nombre)
    return nombre

def modificarNombre():
    nombre = input("\n Digita tu nombre : ")
    print()
    return nombre


nombre = input("\n Digita tu nombre : ")
print()

opcion = 4;

while opcion != 0:
    opcion = int(input("\n Digita una opcion : "))

    if opcion == 1:
        # Imprimir Nombre
        imprimirNombre()

    elif opcion == 2:
        #Modificar Nombre
        # ! Linea de codigo Modificada !
        nombre = modificarNombre() 

    elif opcion == 3:
        # Terminar Ejecucion
        opcion = 0
```